# Wait until view become visible with IdleResource

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-instrumentation

I am writing Instrumentation tests with usage of Espresso 2.2.

Flow I want to test:

1. radioButton clicked by test
2. onClick launches request to API
3. after every time different time I receive response
4. positive response triggers interface method that is called in activity
5. onRequestSuccess I am making additional panel on screen named vSetupAmount visible

I want to register IdleResource after click on radioButton so it waits until vSetupAmount becomes visible. But I can't make it work. Please tell me what am I doing wrong.

I have written such IdleResource:

```
public class AmountViewIdlingResource implements IdlingResource {

    private CountriesAndRatesActivity activity;
    private ResourceCallback callback;

    private SetupAmountView amountView;

    public AmountViewIdlingResource(CountriesAndRatesActivity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;

        amountView = (SetupAmountView) this.activity.findViewById(R.id.vSetupAmount);
    }

    @Override public String getName() {
        return "Amount View idling resource";
    }

    @Override public boolean isIdleNow() {
        callback.onTransitionToIdle();
        return amountView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE;
    }

    @Override public void registerIdleTransitionCallback(ResourceCallback resourceCallback) {
        this.callback = resourceCallback;
    }

}
```

So I am passing activity to IdleResource, link view with variable. I understand that IdleResource won't let test go through until isIdleNow() returns value true. So if view is View.GONE then it won't go further.

How it looks in test:

```
    // click of radioButton picked from radioGroup
    onView(withId(rgDeliveries.getChildAt(id).getId())).perform(scrollTo(), click());

    // wait for view to become visible
    Espresso.registerIdlingResources(new AmountViewIdlingResource(getActivity()));

    // go to button on view
    onView(withId(R.id.btnGetStarted)).perform(scrollTo());

    // unregister idle resource
    for (  IdlingResource resource : getIdlingResources()) {
        Espresso.unregisterIdlingResources(resource);
    }
```

So I get my click on radioButton. IdleResource is successfully registered but nothing happens. On my device API response comes. vSetupAmount is being displayed but

```
amountView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE;
```

which is being checked forever (but I see my view on screen) always returns false.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 16):

I know this might be too late, but my answer might help someone.

1. When you instantiate and register your `AmountViewIdlingResource`, keep a reference to it and only unregister that reference, don't unregister all `IdlingResources`.
2. Your implementation of the `isIdleNow()` method should only call the callback's `onTransitionToIdle()` method if your idling resource is really idle not every time.

I needed to do something similar, to wait for a button to appear on the screen, which in turn only got to be visible after an HTTP call finished. My implementation of a view visibility Idling Resource is as follows:

```
public class ViewVisibilityIdlingResource implements IdlingResource {

    private final View mView;
    private final int mExpectedVisibility;

    private boolean mIdle;
    private ResourceCallback mResourceCallback;

    public ViewVisibilityIdlingResource(final View view, final int expectedVisibility) {
        this.mView = view;
        this.mExpectedVisibility = expectedVisibility;
        this.mIdle = false;
        this.mResourceCallback = null;
    }

    @Override
    public final String getName() {
        return ViewVisibilityIdlingResource.class.getSimpleName();
    }

    @Override
    public final boolean isIdleNow() {
        mIdle = mIdle || mView.getVisibility() == mExpectedVisibility;

        if (mIdle) {
            if (mResourceCallback != null) {
                mResourceCallback.onTransitionToIdle();
            }
        }

        return mIdle;
    }

    @Override
    public void registerIdleTransitionCallback(ResourceCallback resourceCallback) {
        mResourceCallback = resourceCallback;
    }

}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: how do you get the reference to the view?

Comment: Your activity rule in your test allows you to get the activity, then you can use findviewbyid or anything else related

Comment: @HaydenKai see the `setUp()` method here: https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-device-farm-sample-app-for-android/blob/77d7779d69/app/src/androidTest/java/com/amazonaws/devicefarm/android/referenceapp/IdlingResources/WebViewIdlingResource.java